# projecting lat/lng to pixel x,y on google maps

Tags: python, google-maps, gis, proj

In python, I want to convert between lat/lng  (in epsg 4326) to x, y in google maps pixels (assuming the closest zoom level).

`pyproj` lets me convert between projection spaces with code like:

```
>>> p1 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
>>> p2 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857')
>>> pyproj.transform(p1, p2, 10, 10)
>>> pyproj.transform(p1, p2, 10, 10)
(1113194.9079327343, 1118889.9748579597)
```

What I'm not sure about, is the proper projection to use to get the x, y pixels.

There's a PHP implementation of the transformation on this page:
http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps

```
define('OFFSET', 268435456);
define('RADIUS', 85445659.4471); /* $offset / pi() */

function lonToX($lon) {
    return round(OFFSET + RADIUS * $lon * pi() / 180);        
}

function latToY($lat) {
    return round(OFFSET - RADIUS * 
            log((1 + sin($lat * pi() / 180)) / 
            (1 - sin($lat * pi() / 180))) / 2);
}
```

Rather than coding the transform manually in python, I would rather use pyproj, since it will be more flexible, and easier to reverse the transform.

These are the values that implementation gives on the sample point (10, 10):

```
>>> lon_to_x(10)
283348536.88889694

>>> lat_to_y(10)
253446080.30134577
```